# SQL Server Profiler, Management Studio and Operations Studio hang after updating XML Data option

Tags: ssms, sql-server-profiler, azure-data-studio

I've been using SSMS, SQL Server Profiler and SQL Operations Studio for a while now without issue.  However, when some query text (TextData column) was getting truncated in the profiler, I decide to increase the SSMS "XML Data" size to "5 MB".  Now all three applications hang at different spots.

- SSMS and SOS hang when scripting table as a SELECT.
- SQL Profiler hangs after moving past the connection dialog.

In event viewer, I see this error:

> Application: ioc.exe 
>   Framework Version: v4.0.30319 
>   Description: The
>   process was terminated due to an unhandled exception. Exception Info:
>   System.AccessViolationException

It's also important to note, it is definitely not the case that the trace window/connection dialog/etc. is rendering off screen.  Simply, the applications are hanging due to an unhandled exception.

- Restoring Query Results options to default didn't work.
- Relaunching SSMS/SQL Server Profiler/Sql Operations Studio didn't work.
- Rebooting didn't work.
- Running applications as Administrator didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up pointing the connection dialog to another database to see if that made a difference and I was able to connect.  This seems to have jarred something loose; I had to do this for all three applications separately, each time performing the task that hung on prior attempts on a different server fixed the problem.  Though I wish I knew what was happening under the covers, I wasn't able to find any resources describing this same issue.

Once I pointed back to the original database I was able to launch each application successfully.

**UPDATE** - I later found that ioc.exe is Intel's Lenovo bloatware (Intel Online Connect).  A security suite, which I promptly uninstalled.